# TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, urllib2

@Sven @Mozzie
Thank you so much for your sweet help.
my code is  $python download.py

I attached the link of the raw code of download.py as blew. I have stuck in this bug for three days:( I really appreciate your sweet help!

https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-kubernetes-art-classification/blob/master/download.py

I try to compile and install python with openssl support.

Unfortunately, there is a list of error as below.

```
0 (u'Asian Art', u'China', u'http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/41964')
China http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/41964
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/ssl/tensorflow-kubernetes-art-classification/download.py", line 44, in <module>
    html_page = response.read().decode(encoding)
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

Would you please help me how to fix this? If it is possible, would you please write down the exact code for me? I really appreciate your kind help!

Comment: Its impossible to know whats going on without the actual code...

Comment: Hi Mozzie, thank you so much for your comment. I attached the whole code of download.py as below.   https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-kubernetes-art-classification/blob/master/download.py

Comment: It might be possible that there is  an invalid URL in your list. Did you try and print some information about your iteration. Use `for n, item in enumerate(arts_to_download):` and in the beginning of the loop `print n, item`. This can help to show, which iteration of the loop is throwing the error.

Comment: I saw others' post on this kind of error. Someone said to replace ":" with "%3A" url. If it is possible, would you please let me know how to replace ":" with "%3A" url？

Comment: Did you try my code for the loop? First replace the loop header and verify the invalid URL (the last before the error)... You can read the file as a whole string, use the method `replace(':', '%3A')` and write the string object back into the file... And please use @Sven in your comments or @Mozzie if you want to directly talk to us. Then we will be notified by StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sven Hi Sven, thank you so much for your kind help! I try your method to get  0 ('Asian Art', 'China', 'http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/41964')
 'China  'http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/41964
If it is possible, would you please provide the exact code of replace(":", "%3A"). My email is shilinwang0827@gmail. I really appreciate your kind help:)

Comment: Maybe your URLs must start with "http://" or "https://". The error message seems to imply that the protocol cannot be determined. I don't know if this is necessary for `urllib2`. Have a look at your data and try to correct it.